# Drawing multiple polygons in Matlab with no borders

Tags: matlab, graphics, 2d

I'm creating a figure with many polygons which can overlap in Matlab. I do not want borders on any of the shapes, only a translucent fill. I was able to get the first shape to obey this request using:

```
fill(xv,yv,'blue','FaceAlpha',0.1,'EdgeColor','None','LineStyle','none');hold on;
```

However, each subsequent shape which is drawn in the loop ignores this style, instead cycling through colored borders. I was able to use the set command to override the color cycle, but this still draws a border...I do *not* want any border. The border cannot be drawn at all because we are using the overlapping properties of the shapes, and the presence of any borders would perturb the nature of our simulation.

Here is the complete code:

```
for count = 1:92
 x=randn*clustering;
 y=randn*clustering;
 angle=randn*360;
 rectangle(width,height,x,y,angle);
end

function rectangle(w,h,x,y,angle)
 %Define the rectangle
 xv=[x x+w x+w x x];
 yv=[y y y+h y+h y];
 %Define the rotation transformation matrix
 transform=[cos(angle) -sin(angle);sin(angle) cos(angle)];
 %Define the translation to origin transform
 xcenter=x+.5*w;
 ycenter=y+.5*h;
 %Perform translation to origin
 tx=xv-xcenter;
 ty=yv-ycenter;
 %Perform rotation
 rotated=transform*[tx;ty];
 %Perform translation back to original location
 xv=rotated(1,:)+xcenter;
 yv=rotated(2,:)+ycenter;
 %Plot result
 figure(1);
 plot(xv,yv);
 fill(xv,yv,'blue','FaceAlpha',0.1);hold on;
 axis square;
 axis([-30 30 -30 30]);
```

Comment: When I try this code with two different values of the vectors `xv`,  `yv` I don't get any border. What I do get is a different color in the overlapping region, because the two colors "add" there due to alpha

Comment: Well, then for everything you draw do 'EdgeColor', 'none'

Comment: I do not get the border either when I plot multiple polygons. You should show us the code of your loop. There is probably an instruction there which is different than the simple line you gave as example. Also, the function `fill` create a `patch` object and automatically set some properties. If you want more control, use `patch` directly if you can.

Comment: The "addition" of alpha values is exactly what we are after, since it represents the degree of overlapping regions of the shapes.

Comment: The function `fill` works ok, but the line just above you execute: `plot(xv,yv);`. This instruction will draw a line representing the contour of your polygon (which looks like a "border"). Comment this line, add `'EdgeColor','None'` to the parameters of `fill` (just to be sure) and you'll be ok.

Comment: Thanks, Hoki! That worked perfectly! I didn't know that those two commands were redundant; I thought that the fill was applying to the prior "plot". Thank you!